# Does mono really implement the namespace System.AddIn.Hosting?

Tags: c#, mono

The following page shows that mono implements the System.AddIn.Hosting namespace.

[mono api status](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.AddIn)

After not finding a System.AddIn.dll anywhere in mono I looked in mono source.

I've looked in mono, version 2.10.8.1 + mono 3.0.7, source code but have been unable to find it. I looked for "System.AddIn.Hosting" and type names like "AddInSecurityLevel", but found no matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the title in [mono api status](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.AddIn) is misleading, What this page is showing is the differences between .net 4.0 + .net 4.5.

This can be seen from here [mono api status summary page](http://go-mono.com/status/)

So the Answer seems to be: No Mono does not implement System.AddIn.Hosting or any System.AddIn
namespace.

Update:
An opensource implementation of System.Add that runs on Linux with mono can  be found [here](https://hg.sr.ht/%7Ehindlemail/system.addin.dll).